# Parallax animation: How to know which method is used in a webpage?

Tags: html, css, parallax, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm investigating about the different ways of building a website with parallax animations. I've seen a lot of plug-ins and libraries (ScrollMagic, Greensock, etc.), but I would like to know which way have [this webpage](https://koox.co.uk/home) used. I've been diving into the source code, but I don't see any linked script that shows me the way this effect was done in this website.

Could anyone help?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Will probably be hard, but you can always reach out to them and ask them what they use or if it's custom built. Not really ontopic but you can use the site  'wappalyzer' to  see what  technologies website uses.

Comment: Hi Omar, Thank you a lot for your answer. I think that it's going to be hard to get this answer from the developers, but I appreciate a lot your answer!